# How to add a cursor into figure in wxpython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am using wxpython and matplotlib to develop a software,I used the following class named "FigureBasePanel" to add this figure panel into my software.But I can't add a cursor into this figure,the cursor I mentioned is a class in " matplotlib.widgets.Cursor". Is there any method to add a cursor into this panel?
    Here is the FigureBasePanel class.

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import wx

import numpy as np

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("WXAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FuncFormatter

import pylab
from matplotlib import pyplot

class FigureBasePanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent, id=-1)

        self.Figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(4.8,2.3))
        self.axes = self.Figure.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])

        self.FigureCanvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.Figure)

        self.NavigationToolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.FigureCanvas)
        #self.StaticText = wx.StaticText(self,-1,label='')
        self.SubBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SubBoxSizer.Add(self.NavigationToolbar,proportion =1, border = 1,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTER  )
        #self.SubBoxSizer.Add(self.StaticText,proportion =-1, border = 2,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND )

        self.TopBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.TopBoxSizer.Add(self.SubBoxSizer,proportion =0, border = 0,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.TopBoxSizer.Add(self.FigureCanvas,proportion =1, border = 0,flag = wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.TopBoxSizer)

        self.pylab=pylab
        self.pl=pylab
        self.pyplot=pyplot
        self.numpy=np
        self.np=np


    def UpdatePlot(self):
        self.FigureCanvas.draw()


    def plot(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.axes.plot(*args,**kwargs)
        self.UpdatePlot()


    def semilogx(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.axes.semilogx(*args,**kwargs)
        self.UpdatePlot()

    def semilogy(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.axes.semilogy(*args,**kwargs)
        self.UpdatePlot()

    def loglog(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.axes.loglog(*args,**kwargs)
        self.UpdatePlot()


    def grid(self,flag=True):
        if flag:
            self.axes.grid()
        else:
            self.axes.grid(False)


    def title_MPL(self,TitleString="wxMatPlotLib Example In wxPython"):
        self.axes.set_title(TitleString)


    def xlabel(self,XabelString="X"):
        ''' # Add xlabel to the plotting    '''
        self.axes.set_xlabel(XabelString)


    def ylabel(self,YabelString="Y"):
        ''' # Add ylabel to the plotting '''
        self.axes.set_ylabel(YabelString)


    def xticker(self,major_ticker=1.0,minor_ticker=0.1):
        self.axes.xaxis.set_major_locator( MultipleLocator(major_ticker) )
        self.axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator( MultipleLocator(minor_ticker) )


    def yticker(self,major_ticker=1.0,minor_ticker=0.1):
        self.axes.yaxis.set_major_locator( MultipleLocator(major_ticker) )
        self.axes.yaxis.set_minor_locator( MultipleLocator(minor_ticker) )


    def legend(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.axes.legend(*args,**kwargs)


    def xlim(self,x_min,x_max):
        self.axes.set_xlim(x_min,x_max)


    def ylim(self,y_min,y_max):
        self.axes.set_ylim(y_min,y_max)


    def savefig(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.Figure.savefig(*args,**kwargs)


    def cla(self):
        self.axes.clear()
        self.Figure.set_canvas(self.FigureCanvas)
        self.UpdatePlot()

    def ShowHelpString(self,HelpString="Show Help String"):
        self.StaticText.SetLabel(HelpString)
```

Comment: Why can't you add the matplotlib.widgets.Cursor to your figure? What is the error that you get? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Thank you,I have already resolve this problem :-)